# Linear Regression with a Dummy/Categorical Variable

Tags: r, linear-regression

For example I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2010, 2010,2010,2010, 2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020),
                          income=c(45000, 48000, 54000, 57000, 65000, 69000,
                          78000, 83000, 98000, 104000, 107000),
                 age=c(23, 25, 24, 29, 38, 36, 40, 59, 56, 64, 53))

dummy <- ifelse(df$year == '2010', 1, 0) #create a dummy variable for the year

#create data frame to use for regression
df_reg <- data.frame(year = df$year,
                     income = df$income,
                     age = df$age,
                     dummy = dummy)
```

Now I want to use regression analysis to find the relationship like this:

Dependent Variable = `α1` + `δ1`× Independent Variable + `α2` × Dummy + `δ2` × Dummy × Independent Variable

So here, the coefficients, `α1` and `δ1`, are interpreted as the relationship between the dependent and the independent variable of interest in the year 2010. The coefficients, `α2` and `δ2`, are interpreted as the change in the relationship between 2010 and 2020, so these latter two coefficients are testing if the observations in the year of 2010 is significantly different from the year of 2020 behavior. Dependent variable is `$income` and independent variable is `$age` in this case.

I've tried this code:

```
model <- lm(income ~ age + dummy, data=df_reg)
```

However I expected two intercept values in `summary(model)` (not one), one is for the relationship for between `income` and `age` in the year of 2010, and the other one is as the change relationship between 2010 and 2020.

Am I missing something here, or did I have to use another method?

Thanks and appreciating your response.

Comment: The linear model has only one intercept, and coefficients for each dummy variable, and of course coefficients for other variables as well. Note that your code does not match the model you are describing in your question. You would write it `model <- lm(income ~ age * dummy, data = df_reg) ` or `model <- lm(income ~ age + dummy + I(age * dummy), data = df_reg) `

Comment: Yes I see your point now, I guess I misinterpreted the outputs, thank you!